# Replacement for obsolete "statement functions" in Fortran 95 and later?

Tags: function, macros, fortran, fortran95

### Original Question

As I understand, as of Fortran 95 Statement functions have been declared obsolete in favor of internal functions. However, internal functions do not cover all use-cases, in particular when using statement functions as abbreviations with implied arguments for making the implementation of long formulas more readable. Is there any adequate replacement for this usecase?

#### Example

E.g., lets say we have an relation

Cᵢⱼ = ∫dx₁∫dx₂∫dx₃∫dy₁∫dy₂∫dy₃ (AᵢⱼBᵢⱼ +BᵢⱼAⱼᵢ)

E.g. compare an implementation using directly the internal representation of A,B with the index-order mandated by prior code, resulting in

```
do a1=1,NGRID1; do a2=1,NGRID2; ...; do aN=1,NGRIDN
  x(i,j) = x(i,j) &
      & + ARR_A(x1,x2,x3,i,y1,y2,y3,j)*ARR_B(x1,x2,x3,i,y1,y2,y3,j) &
      & + ARR_B(x1,x2,x3,i,y1,y2,y3,j)*ARR_A(x1,x2,x3,i,y1,y2,y3,j)
end do; end do; ...; end do
```

to an implementation using statement functions as abbreviation,

```
A(i,j) = ARR_A(x1,x2,x3,i,y1,y2,y3,j)
B(i,j) = ARR_B(x1,x2,x3,i,y1,y2,y3,j)
...
do x1=1,NGRID1; do x2=1,NGRID2; ...; do y3=1,NGRIDN
  x(i,j) = x(i,j) + A(i,j)*B(i,j) + B(i,j)*A(i,j)
end do; end do; ...; end do
```

In the second version it seems much easier to spot the mixed-uo order of the indices after noticing that there *is* an issue.

#### Using macros?

The only method to achieve similar semantics I found was using preprocessor macros. Typically, C-style macros are used, which here would lead to

```
#define A(i,j) ARR_A(x1,x2,x3,i,y1,y2,y3,j)
```

but this sacrifices scoping of the name. While this seems potentially useful, especially when the same abbreviation is used accross multiple functions, it seems potentially rather confusing. For a start, the compiler will give more useful error messages, when using statement functions incorrectly than it can for macros.

It also introduces the need to manually `#undefine` the name, if we want to reuse the same name in different contexts for different things.

### Solution (1)

I had misunderstood how `CONTAINS` and internal functions work (see [IanH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45989229/2075630) and its comments).

Short: Internal functions can be defined inside subroutines with `CONTAINS`, and work exactly like statement functions, except for a more verbose syntax.

<strike>The misunderstanding arose partly because it apparently is *not* allowed to define a subroutine inside a subroutine in this manner.</strike> Apparently it does work. No idea what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Why don't internal functions cover this use case?

Comment: a toy example i suppose, but you could just do `2*A(i,j)*B(i,j)`

Comment: You are wrong again. It is perfectly possible to define a subroutine inside a subroutine.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I honestly have no idea, what I did wrong when I tried before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internal procedures are pretty much a drop-in replacement for statement functions for this use case, with their usual benefits of more capability and less proneness to error, at the cost of some slight extra verbosity with their definition.

```
MODULE some_module     ! Just for the sake of example.
  ...
CONTAINS
  ! The host of the internal procedure.  This could 
  ! also be an external procedure or a main program.
  ! It could also be a function.
  SUBROUTINE some_subroutine
    ...
    DO i = 1, 3
      DO j = 1, 3
        DO x1 = 1, 3
          DO x2 = 1, 3
            ...
            x(i,j) = x(i,j) + A(i,j)*B(i,j) + B(i,j)*A(i,j)
            ...
          END DO
        END DO
      END DO
    END DO     
    ...      
  CONTAINS
    ! An internal procedure.  For different use cases 
    ! this could also be a subroutine.
    FUNCTION A(i,j)
      INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: i,j
      REAL :: A
      A = ARR_A(x1,x2,x3,i,y1,y2,y3,j)
    END FUNCTION A

    FUNCTION B(i,j)
      INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: i,j
      REAL :: B
      B = ARR_B(x1,x2,x3,i,y1,y2,y3,j)
    END FUNCTION B
    ...
 END SUBROUTINE some_subroutine
 ...
END MODULE some_module
```

Note that the maximum array rank under the rules of Fortran 77/90/95/2003 is seven.

Comment: While this works, it introduces global variables (on the level of the `PROGRAM` or `MODULE`) which are pretty much universally frowned upon - at least outside of Fortran. Especially when I need the abbreviation inside only a single subroutine, I'd rather limit their scope to where they are needed; Making loop-variables global (even if flagged "private") seems potentially confusing. Statement functions allow this by being defined inside the subroutine. With internal functions, I'd have to split my module into several modules to achieve something similar.

Comment: I think you misunderstand internal procedures.  The scope of the variables that are host associated into the internal procedure is *exactly the same* as the scope of the variables associated into the statement function.  Internal procedures are defined *inside* their host procedure - that's why they are called "internal"!

Comment: It seems I've figured out the problem; I was expecting the `CONTAINS` inside a subroutine to allow the same things like the `COTAINS` inside a module, but apparently it does *not* allow defining nested subroutines. I also wasn't aware, that it is not allowed to `CALL`  a function for side-effects, which added to the confusion.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include the leading `SUBROUTINE` declaration? Due to my misunderstanding of how internal functions work, which lead to the misinterpretation, that `CONTAINS` inside subroutines were not allowed, I wrongly assumed that the code only works inside a `PROGRAM`, but not inside a `SUBROUTINE`.

Comment: The host of an internal procedure may also be a function, or it could be the main program.  If the host is a procedure, it may be a module procedure.  You can call a function for side effects (though some prefer not to as a matter of style), but there are some restrictions that must be observed by the programmer.  As Vladimir notes, you can have an internal procedure that is a subroutine.